# How to use Tensorflow and keras with non-internet access environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i tried to use tensorflow and keras with my pc(windows X64, non-internet access environment). so i downloaded anaconda(python 3.8) and installed.
then i also downloaded tensorflow(version 2.5.0, from pypi.org) and keras(version 2.4.3, from pypi.org)
from internet access environment then moved to non-internet environment pc
well, i finished installation with following instructions

1. keras : python setup.py install
2. tensorflow : pip install --no-deps "c:\some-path\filename.whl

and then tried to use them but errors were occured.

i don't know what was wrong and how to solve this problems
please give me some ideas! thank you:)

Comment: We cannot help you if you do not include the error messages that you got.

Comment: @SeunghoKang, As rightly mentioned by Dr.Snoopy, without error messages it is very difficult to investigate the issue. By the way, there is a incompatibility between `Tensorflow 2.5` and `keras 2.4.3`, so can you try with `keras 2.5.0rc0` and see if it solve your issue. If it doesn't, can add error message? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!